# Best way to run a batch (shell / CMD) command in Java / Eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, testng

I have created the following code below in Eclipse / java which executes a batch file, which in turn should also execute once all my TestNG tests have executed but sometimes the bat file will execute and sometimes it dosnt do anything at all, any ideas?

```
@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true) 
public void executeBatFile() {
    try {
        List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList("cmd", "/c", "copyPasteImgs.bat");
        File dir = new File(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/..").toRealPath() + "\\");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
        pb.directory(dir);
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The batch files moves files from a local folder to a remote folder (When the batch file hasnt worked via eclipse or invoked via jenkins I have manually executed the batch file and it did its jobs, very weird...)

thanks for your help

Comment: Is is possible, that the script is executed, but the files can't be moved (because files are still locked)? Maybe adding a log output in the batch script would be helpful.

Comment: @guenhter thanks allot for the comment. do you have any resources / link that would show me how to create a log from a batch file? thanks allot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) provides functionalities to handle using command line from java. You can also use the exit value to have an idea about what is going on with your command. For example:

```
String command = "dir";
CommandLine oCmdLine = CommandLine.parse(command);
        DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
        oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
        try {
            int iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(oCmdLine);
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            System.err.println("Execution failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("permission denied.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thnaks so much where would i point to the batch file or add the code from my batch file?

Comment: I think you can use the full path to your batch file in `command`, or you could also parse your file and use use its content, it's pretty much the same